# Dúvida em VBA Excel 2013

Tags: banco-de-dados, microsoft-excel, vba

Tenho este bocado de codigo:

```
  Range("F8").Select

  For Each m In Range(Range("C8"), Range("C" & rows.Count).End(xlUp))

     If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0) <> " " Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) = Application.vlookup(ActiveCell, Sheets("Chargeback code-Pursuit").Range("A2:B20000"), 2, False)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
     End If

  Next
```

E ao fazer isto aparece os dados pretendidos, mas qd a celula c8 está vazia o campo que esta a preencher com o vlookup está a aparecer como #N/A.

Como faço para as cells que contem o #N/A se tornarem blank cells?

Em baixo está o exemplo do #N/A

Obrigado pela ajuda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

você pode adicionar a fórmula `IFERROR`:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) = Application.iferror(Application.vlookup(ActiveCell, Sheets("Chargeback code-Pursuit").Range("A2:B20000"), 2, False),"")
```

o

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) = Application.vlookup(ActiveCell, Sheets("Chargeback code-Pursuit").Range("A2:B20000"), 2, False)
If IsError(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7)) Then ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) = ""
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas não esta a funcionar @virtualdvid dá erro de sub or function not defined :S

Comment: Desculpe meu erro, o problema é porque o `vlookup` não é um recurso VBA. Eu corrigi a minha resposta, diga-me se funciona :)

Comment: Para tal tenho de colocar a função numa sheet certo? Porque atualmente da erro de Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class

Comment: Tente o `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(arg1,arg2,arg2,[arg4])`

Comment: Você quer a fórmula ou apenas o valor na célula?

Comment: Como está no codigo que mostrei funciona, so que nao consigo evitar os #N/A e é somente isso que pretendo fazer.

Comment: Você tenta a primeira linha da minha resposta? `Application.iferror(Application.vlookup(`

Comment: Sim, e deu o erro de Sub or function not defined

Comment: Corri que essa linha estava faltando `Application.` no `vlookup` 
você pode tentar novamente com esta linha.Eu também estou trabalhando em outra resposta possível. Eu atualizarei minha resposta em breve.

Comment: A segunda opção nao passa por aqui Then ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) = " " é normal? continua a dar o #N/A

Comment: Consegui resolver:                                                                                  
 [  For Each M In Range(Range("C8"), Range("C" & 
     rows.Count).End(xlUp))

       ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) = Application.vlookup(ActiveCell, Sheets("Chargeback code-Pursuit").Range("A2:B20000"), 2, False)
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
If IsError(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7)) Then ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) = ""

Next
Cells.Replace "#N/A", "", xlWhole]